# Remove and insert dynamixel

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently using some custom dynamixel controller, but was looking into ways so that when I remove and re-insert the USB cable of the dynamixels, it would automatically reconnect. At the moment it gives a fatal error when removing the USB cable. I saw there was a dynamixel_motor package in ROS, is such a thing possible with this package? If it is, then I will take the trouble of replacing my current custom controller with the ROS package.

Another solution is adding respawn="true" in the launch file for my controller, but since there is no wait time in this respawn and the node gives a fatal error immediately when no dynamixel is connected, it 'spams' the spawning of this node. I would rather have it spare the CPU and try once every second.

Any ideas?

ps. I am asking cause I want a setup where I just have to switch on a laptop, upstart scripts launch all necessary nodes and motors are automatically initialized and re-initialized if inserted again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34250/remove-and-insert-dynamixel/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dynamixel_motor stack currently doesn't support automatic restart when the USB dongle is reinserted. I also thought that a feature like that might be useful, but I never had the time to really think about how it would be implemented. In short, dynamixel_motor stack won't solve you problem at this time.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0